# Can we use more master nodes instead of ‘coordinating only’?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nodes

We have an issue that is supposed to be resolved by adding 'coordinating only' nodes:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/why-am-i-seeing-bulk-rejections-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster

But on AWS (it might be a special case due to the fact that we are using internal company system built on top of AWS for security reasons) we can't have them it seems, but we can add more master and data nodes. Would addition of master nodes be as effective or only a bit less effective, would they take any roles of 'coordinating only' ones? What are other reasonable solutions to the problem?

Link to the same question on `Elasticsearch` forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-we-use-more-master-nodes-instead-of-coordinating-only/266123

Comment: Basically we have 3 master nodes and 3 data nodes. For 10Gb files processing it was fine, but when we switched to 120Gb ones - the problem started. We see an error where queue size = 200 and queue is 200, so we could increase queue size, but that seems not recommended.

Comment: @jordanm master nodes are not coordinating only. The latter are [by definition nodes without any roles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-only-node). It is a bad practice to use master-eligible nodes as coordinating nodes. Master-eligible nodes should only do master tasks and not have to deal with user queries or ingest tasks

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko increasing the queue size will only hide the problem and push it further. What you need to do is simply send smaller bulks and wait for each to complete before sending another one

Comment: How to send smaller bulks? You mean reduce 'block_size' parameter (currently it is set to  `5000`? Just post the question if you are sure, I will check it and then accept the answer if it solves the issue.

Comment: How are you currently sending your data? Can you explain your ingestion process in more details?

Comment: I am using Hail's `export_elasticsearch` function - https://hail.is/docs/0.2/methods/impex.html#hail.methods.export_elasticsearch - `block_size` corresponds to `es.batch.size.entries`, sorry, didn't specify it. I added the link above to `elasticsearch` forum where in the last answer I describe what I have in terms of computing environment.